# Firestore addSnapshotListener is querying all data when a new document added - Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore to save objects but realize that when a new document added to collection, firestore reading quota increases by number of document that query returns. Am I doing firestore reading with wrong way ? is there a better way to reduce the number of readings ?

I mean that is there a way like that check only new added document if query right for it and if yes return this and add to arraylist. I am asking this question because if query returns 50 items when a new document added quota will decrease by 50. If 10 new document added quota will increase by 500.

```
 Query transactionsQuery = IOTransactions
            .whereLessThan("timestamp", dateOfToday())
            .whereGreaterThan("timestamp", findDaysAgo())
            .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .limit(40);
    transactionsQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w("FirestoreDemo", "Listen failed.", e);
                return;
            }

            for (DocumentChange dc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                switch (dc.getType()) {
                    case ADDED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "New city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                        transactionsList.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(StockTransaction.class));
                        break;
                    case MODIFIED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Modified city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                        break;
                    case REMOVED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Removed city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                        transactionsList.remove(dc.getDocument().toObject(StockTransaction.class));
                        break;
                }
            }
```

While checking the code and quota I realized that if I use whereLessThan and whereGreaterThan methods reading counts by 40 which is limit value. However if I delete where methods, reading counts only 1. I think it seems like a bug because query can check only added element. For example when new document added to this collection, check it for query, if it is true for query then return new added document, if false do nothing.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually being **billed** for reads as you say?  If you have a listener attached to a query, and a new document is added, you should only be **billed** for one new read, but the listener will give you all the documents to work with in every callback.  Those other documents come from local memory, not read at the server.

Comment: I am not totally sure but I only add about 50 document but reading quota increased to 1.5 k it was 100 before adding documents.

Comment: If you're unclear about how billing works, or think there is a bug, you should contact Firebase support directly.  As I said, documents that come from memory should not get billed when used.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: Thank you, I will try and write the answer here.

Comment: I think I found the problem with counts. whereLessThan and whereGreaterThan methods are the problem. If I don't use this methods and query again it counts only 1. However if I query with these methods it counts by 40 which is my limit method's value. Do you think that it is a problem ? In my opinion this is a bug because query can return only last added item if query right for this item.

Comment: Now I am totally sure the problem is where clauses. As I see it doesn't use cache with where clauses and this is not only for add operations, query works every time when fragment newly created.  @DougStevenson

Comment: @DougStevenson how do you know if document data is "coming from memory" and thus not billed against you?